# MVC .net core: Validator.TryValidateObject is not validating attributes, defined in a buddy class

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations, asp.net-core-3.1, buddy-class

We used DB-first approach to generate models in a .NET core application. DataAnnotations were put in a "buddy" metadata class so as to avoid writing in an autogenerated file. When controller calls TryValidateModel, all works well, Name property is required.

```
public partial class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ModelMetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
public partial class User : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) { }
}

public class UserMetaData
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

On a service layer of the app, we want to implement additional validation, that also checks if objects are valid in regards to data annotations. This is done via
`Validator.TryValidateObject()`
which successfully calls Validate method, but disregards data annotations - user is valid, even with an empty name.

TL;DR:
MVC (web project) knows how to consider data annotations put in a "buddy" class via ModelMetadataType attribute, service layer project does not.

I thought i have found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422031/validation-does-not-work-when-i-use-validator-tryvalidateobject/2467360#2467360), but it seems that
`TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent`
does not work for .net **core** apps.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really hoped for a one line solution :)

I abused [ashrafs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422031/validation-does-not-work-when-i-use-validator-tryvalidateobject/2428028#2428028) to his own question like so:

```
var metadataAttr = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ModelMetadataTypeAttribute), true).OfType<ModelMetadataTypeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
if (metadataAttr != null)
{
    var metadataClassProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(metadataAttr.MetadataType).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();
    var modelClassProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();

    var errs =
        from metaProp in metadataClassProperties
        join modelProp in modelClassProperties
        on metaProp.Name equals modelProp.Name

        from attribute in metaProp.Attributes.OfType<ValidationAttribute>()
        where !attribute.IsValid(modelProp.GetValue(model))
        select new ValidationResult(attribute.FormatErrorMessage(Reflector.GetPropertyDisplayName<T>(metaProp.Name)), new[] { metaProp.Name });

    validationResults.AddRange(errs);
}
```